# Prevent scientific writing when creating a file through Snakemake

Tags: python, python-3.x, snakemake

Not sure if it's a Python issue or a Snakemake issue, but I have this target:

```
SCORES = expand(expand(RESULTS_DIR + "/{{sp}}_{{st}}/{{seq}}/scores/{tf}_{th}.scores.tab", zip, tf=TF_NAME, th=TF_THR), sp=SPECIES, st=STRAINS, seq=SEQ)
```

where TF_THR is a list of floats. In some cases, the output file is written using scientific notation, which I wanna prevent from happening. I tried this:

```
th='{:.6f}'.format(TF_THR)
```

and this:

```
th=format(TF_THR, '0.6f'))
```

but in both cases I get the following error:

```
TypeError in line 44 of myworkflow.py:
unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__
  File "myworkflow.py", line 44, in <module>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: To me the actual issue seems to be that you try to format the whole list at once - which won't work. Use e.g. `th=['{:.6f}'.format(t) for t in TF_THR]` or `expand` instead.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which values of TF_THR give `'{:.6f}'.format(x)` in scientific notation? I tried a few and I don't get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand, just like all strings in Python, makes use of the '[format minilang](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)'. I'm not sure how well this is documented for Snakemake.

To solve your issue we can simply do something like this:

```
TF_THR = [0.12345, 0.6789]
print(expand('{th:0.3f}', th=TF_THR))
# ['0.123', '0.679']
```